# Writing my first Ant task: what am I missing?

Tags: xml, ant, taskdef

I have read [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) article and used it to write my first Ant task called `AutoTestTask`:

```
public class AutoTestTask extends org.apache.tools.ant.Task {
    // ...
}
```

I have also compiled and packaged this object into `auto-test.jar`.

If my understanding of Ant is correct, then to include it as part of another project's build, I use the following XML:

```
<project name="SomeProject" basedir="." default="deploy" xmlns:at="antlib:org.me.auto-test">
    <!-- Task definitions. -->
    <taskdef name="at-autotest" classname="org.me.auto-test.AutoTestTask"/>

    <!-- Use the task. -->
    <at:autotest/>
</project>
```

I *believe* I also need to copy `auto-test.jar` into my ${ANT_HOME}/lib directory - **can someone please confirm?** What's confusing me is the `xmlns:at="antlib:org.me.auto-test"` attribute at the top of the XML, and specifically, the `antlib:<whatever>` portion. Is this some kind of Ant-specific protocol that says "*anything qualified by the `at` namespace will be found inside ${ANT_HOME}/lib with a root package of `org.me.auto-test`*"? If not could someone explain what it means?

Also, if I'm missing anything obvious or have anything configured incorrectly, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's simpler than you think, but you have to be a bit careful.

The first problem is `<taskdef name="at-autotest" .. />`, because then you try to use the task as "at:autotest". "at" is the xml namespace prefix, so you need to drop the "at-" at the beginning of your taskdesk definition.

The second problem is that you haven't associated your taskdef with the xml namespace "antlib:org.me.auto-test", so you can't use the prefix. At this stage, you could use it with the current namespace (i.e. no prefix) as in `<autotest/>`. But I encourage you to specify a separate namespace for all your external tasks, so the correct version is:

```
<project name="SomeProject" basedir="." default="deploy" xmlns:at="antlib:org.me.auto-test">
    <!-- Task definitions. -->
    <taskdef name="autotest" classname="org.me.auto-test.AutoTestTask" uri="antlib:org.me.auto-test"/>

    <!-- Use the task. You can use the prefix "at:" here -->
    <at:autotest/>
</project>
```

A couple more things:

1. this setup forces you to place your jar for the task class into  ${ANT_HOME}/lib. But you don't have to do this, you can refer to the jar directly if you know the location (for example, a lib folder in your project root folder). You can specify a classpath containing the jar with `<taskdef>`, as in (assuming you have defined that classpath and assigned id="autotest.classpath"):

   ```
   <!-- Task definitions. -->
   <taskdef name="autotest" classname="org.me.auto-test.AutoTestTask" 
          uri="antlib:org.me.auto-test" classpathref="autotest.classpath" />
   ```
2. As suggested by another person here, you can package your class in an antlib altogether. The only difference with the jar is that it includes a file 'antlib.xml" and that you can even skip the taskdef declaration if this jar is in the main classpath already. Read up [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html%20here). This is where the "antlib:" namespace prefix brings some bonus. I personally don't like putting things in  ${ANT_HOME}/lib so I'm happy to use the `<taskdef />` with the classpath, but I would still recommend to package your jar as an antlib, and to use antlib: as a namespace prefix as a convention anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. I can't compile a package with a hyphen, so I suggest you change `auto-test` to `autotest`
2. In `taskdef` you have `at-autotest`, should be `autotest`
3. `xmlns` declaration is for xml parser and for using antlibs. You don't need to use them for your first ant task. So: remove `xmlns` and `at:` prefix.

Since you ask "What am I missing", please report what is the error message you get. Possibly after following the above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to package your task as an [antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html). The XML file will match the namespace and contain the taskdef operation.

antlibs are relatively new, which might explain why some older "how to create an ANT task" tutorials make no mention of them.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly creating a new ant task via extending `org.apache.tools.ant.Task` is overkill.
Notice there are other ways too :
Use [**scriptdef**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) combined with a scripting language that has full access to ant api i.e.Groovy, Javascript
(jdk >= 6 ships with with its own builtin javascript engine based on rhino 1.6) to define a task inside ant.
To bundle your stuff afterwards create some commons.xml that contains all your [**scriptdef**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) and [**macrodef**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) and use import to make it available for other ant scripts.